# Simple application that simulates a bluetooth accessory

Tags: java, bluetooth

I'm looking for a no-brain application that allows me to send a pre-defined list of commands through a bluetooth connection, or an equivalent Java/Scala library that works decently in OSX (64bits).

In short, I want to use my computer to "simulate" a bluetooth accessory, so I must be able to control the pairing, the exchanged code, and so on...

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Simulating `jsr-82` can be done with the BlueCove Emulator Module:

http://bluecove.org/bluecove-emu/

http://bluecove.org/ works on OS/X and am sure there wouldn't be any issues with a 64bit OS.

I'd refer you to this Answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/20195/bluetooth-emulator

You may want to reconsider your question...

> To emulate a bluetooth device you would need to develop a bluetooth driver getting it's input from a different source, this would be far more complex than buying a real device.

If you are looking to get some NMEA data though, you may be interested in this:

Most bluetooth enabled phones have apps that do that:

Android: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cajax.gps2bt2

Any J2ME: http://www.digitalmobilemap.com/bluetooth-gps-simulator-for-j2me-phone

Haven't found one for iPhone, only reference it can be done: http://spench.net/drupal/software/iphone-gps

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Can you be more exact?
Simulate a Bluetooth accessory for ..?
There are different BT accessories for different smartphones...

Making a BT accessory for iPhone usually requires an authentication chip from Apple...I don't know if a Mac can do it, probably it could - however I'm pretty sure it couldn't describe itself as an accessory.

Accessories usually imply a piece of hardware, in my understanding at least.

Comment: It doesn't need any special capabilities. For a practical example, let's imagine I'm trying to simulate a GPS receiver that sends NMEA messages through a bluetooth connection.

Comment: Here is what another project has done, in order to connect from mobile phone(with Java, including Android) to a such GPS receiver. You need to get a BT dongle, make it discoverable, emulate the service your phone(your 64 bit PC, in your case) is searching for, and accept connection. I suggest using Python and [PyBluez](http://code.google.com/p/pybluez/). Hope this helps